# search for index in array by value with multiple reapeated values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing

i have some code like this

```
dim pos, arr, val
arr = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
val = "b"

pos = Application.Match(val, arr, False)
If Not IsError(pos) Then
MsgBox pos
End If
```

this works fine

except now i need to do something more complicated what if I have an array like

```
arr = Array("a", "b", "b", "b","c","c","d")
```

and I want to return the indexes for all occurences of that value in the array.

I know you can use isinarray but that would just tell you if the value exisists, I need to know which indexs in the array contain the specified value.

Is there a way to do this without looping through the entire array?

Comment: Not without looping.

Comment: Don't be afraid of looping arrays. It's quite efficient.  (What's _not_ efficient is looping over a range).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a function that contains two loop (like a `for`) and store in other array (`indexes`) the positions to be returned. It's probably looks like this pseudocode:

```
function(int[] getIndexes -> { char[] array, char value }) 
    int indexes_found -> 0

    // Supposing that the array position starts at zero. 
    // This is to know the size of idexes array.
    for(int array_pos -> 0, array_pos < sizeof(array), array_pos -> array_pos + 1)

        if(value isEqualsTo array[array_pos])
            indexes_found -> indexes_found + 1
        end(if)
    end(for)

    // The array to be returned will have a size of idexes_found value.
    int[idexes_found] indexes

    // This is to get the next position in indexes array.
    // Remember, size ofindexes is less than or equals to size of array
    int index_pos -> 0

    for(int array_pos -> 0, array_pos < sizeof(array), array_pos -> array_pos + 1)
        if(value isEqualsTo array[array_pos])
            idexes[index_pos] -> array_pos
            index_pos -> index_pos + 1
        end(if)
    end(for)

    return idexes
end(function)
```

I/O example:

Input:

```
char[5] letters -> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b' }
char value -> 'b'

int[] indexes -> getIndexes(letters, value)
```

Output:

```
indexes -> { 1, 4 }
```

Hope help to you.

Greetings.